# ArcCatalog - Script - Parameter - Choose a previous one

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters, arccatalog

I am working on a script that automates the following process: from coordinates in excel spreadsheet to a map in mxd or kmz.

Because the set of coordinates are in two different zones, I have to perform a merge to join them. This last geoprocess generates the final zone of the merge if the user places the first layer in their configuration.

But the data set for one region bears zone 18 and for another dataset it bears zone 19.

In the following screenshot you will see the final product of the script but in ArcCatalog format:

[image]

My question is whether I can choose any of the two layers, but with the generalized name. The parameters are "Feature Class", but I think it is not the one indicated because when I enter it it tells me that it does not exist (Input):

[image]

I want to do this so that I don't have to script a dataset with an H18 zone and another dataset with an H19 zone.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you wanting to pick one feature class or the other? Not both. You can make one or both of the parameters optional. You could get really fancy and using Tool Validation make updates to the control and disable one input.

Comment: What I want to do is put "DS_REGION_MM_AAAA_T_H18" and "DS_REGION_MM_YAAA_T_H19" in Merge_management, where the latter is found in the script with the names "DS_REGION_MM_AAAA_T_HP" (layer with the predominant zone) and "DS_REGION_MM_AAAA_T_HS" (layer with the secondary zone).
The idea is to define who goes first in order to define the spindle of the salient layer.

Comment: The problem is that if I put in "DS_REGION_MM_AAAA_T_HP" (INPUT) the layer that I want to be with the predominant zone, it tells me that it does not exist, because when I enter the values of the parameters in the script it is not yet created, for Hence, it does not exist. How can I configure an INPUT type meter that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: I don't understand. It seems you want to do something with validation to control how the UI works. I can only offer you a [help link to read more](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/customizing-script-tool-behavior.htm) on this, else someone else may understand what you're after.